# How do you use Webpack to generate .html files from Handlebar templates with context?

Tags: webpack, handlebars.js

I'm trying to generate some files using handlebars, and I want some configuration parameters to be included in the context during rendering time.

We tried to create a loader, this works for generating the handlebars templates, but there seems to be no way of actually passing in the context.

```
{
  test: /\.html$/,
    loader: 'handlebars-loader',
    query: {
    extensions: ['.html'],
    **context**: { **// THIS IS A PSEUDO CODE, There doesn't seem to actually be a way to pass in context**
      root: config.public_cdn_url,
      some_other_properties: "one two three"
    },
    partialDirs: [
      config.dir_partials
    ]
  }
}
```

How do you add context variables to handlebars-loader?